# ¿Como puedo insertar en una cadena (Textbox) en la pocisión donde esta el cursor? Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.7

quiero adjuntar una cadena en un TEXTBOX, y lo realizo,  pero siempre se adjunta al final del texto, ¿Existe una manera de adjuntarlo donde esté ubicado el cursor, sin saber las coordenadas?

```
def  adjuntar_receta(self):
    self.valorhab = ""
    self.editar_texto_activar()
    self.formula=Text()
    formula_tipo='\n' + '---------- TRATAMIENTO ----------' 
    self.mitexto_consulta.insert(END, formula_tipo)        
    self.mitexto_consulta.insert(END, '\n' + self.mitexto_recipe_consulta.get(1.0, END))    
    if self.valorhab == "yes" or self.valorhab == "":       
        messagebox.showinfo("A T E N C I O N ! ! !", "El TX fué adjuntado exitosamente!!!")
```

Afradezco si existe alguna manera de insertar siempre donde el cursor se encuentre en el TEXTBOX.

Comment: Usa INSERT en lugar de END. Aquí tienes una buena documentación sobre los indices en el widget Text: https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/text-index.html

Comment: Excelente, muchisimas gracias, me funciono perfecto.

Comment: De nada Juan c: